# Open function in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have been creating an application in qt. I have added open function in it, but was happening that when I open an already open file, it again opens the same file instead of pointing it to already opened file.

```
void MainWindow::actionOpen()
{
    QFileInfo fileInfo = UIUtils::openFile(this);
    if (!fileInfo.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    if (!MainWindow::mdiMode && !maybeSave()) {
        return;
    }

    openFile(fileInfo.filePath());
}
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100 % clear on what the issue is, but if you don't want to run the openFile function on files you've previously opened, you have to keep a record.
For instance, define a QList in your header file:

```
QList<QFileInfo> knownFiles;
```

And then keep it up to date and check it:

```
void MainWindow::actionOpen()
{
    QFileInfo fileInfo = UIUtils::openFile(this);
    if (!fileInfo.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    if (!MainWindow::mdiMode && !maybeSave()) {
        return;
    }

    bool fileIsKnown = false;
    for(qint64 i=0; i<knownFiles.length(); i++)
      if(knownFiles.at(i) == fileInfo)
      {
        fileIsKnown = true;
        break;
      }
    if(!fileIsKnown)
    {
      knownFiles << fileInfo;
      openFile(fileInfo.filePath());
    }
}
```

I don't know what you mean when you say "instead of pointing it to already opened file.".

Comment: I Mean to say, If I have open a new file which has opened in a window. My application opens a new window for same file, instead to go at previous window for the same file.

Comment: I want to prevent open file twice in my application.

Comment: Without seeing your entire code, is a bit hard to say preciesly what you should do. However, if you open a new window for each file, you can just call show() on it in case the file is known.